# Create new this on method call

Tags: node.js, oop, method-chaining

This may be a stupid question, but is it possible to create a new this on a method call of a class?
E.g:

```js
const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.a(1).b(2));
// for example, outputs 3 (1+2)
// the a method will create a new namespace and attach 1 to it, and b will use that new namespace
console.log(foo.b(2));
// this will result in an error, as there is no new namespace from the a method anymore, so b cannot add to anything?
```

Maybe this is too hard to understand, sorry.

```
class Foo {
  a(number) {
    this.a = number;
    return this;
  }
  b(number) {
    return this.a + number;
  }
}
```

This would be the code where it uses the same this variable - this doesn't fit what I wanted but is what I currently have.

```
// pseudo
class Foo {
  a(number) {
    const uniqueVariable = number
    return uniqueVariable
    // it'll somehow pass the number from this method to the next method
  }
  // where it can be used with the second method's input
  b(uniqueVariable, number) {
    return uniqueVariable + number
  }
}
foo.a(1).b(2) = 3
```

This example would obviously cause an error because the return value of a() a number, not something to use a method on again.
Please let me know if I need to explain further -- I'm having some struggle explaining it properly.

Comment: Only `class Foo { ... }`, not `class Foo() { ... }`. Remove your `()` from `class Foo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is that `foo.a(1).b(2)` changes `foo`, or if you don't mind changing `foo`, the other answers here work.

But if you *only* want `foo.a(1).b(2)` to return `3` *without* modifying `foo`, then you need to return a new `Foo`.

Now, if you really hell bent on having `console.log()` print `3` rather than something like `Foo { value: 3 }`, you can also customize `inspect()` (given that the question is tagged with `node.js`).

All together:

```
const util = require('util');

class Foo {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value || 0;
    }

    add(value) {
        return new Foo(this.value + value);
    }

    a(value) {
        return this.add(value);
    }

    b(value) {
        return this.add(value);
    }

    [util.inspect.custom]() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo);
console.log(foo.a(2).b(1));
console.log(foo);
```

Output:

```
0
3
0
```

Answer (score 0):

On my solution, I decided to create two variables to hold the values of each method. (https://jsbin.com/wozuyefebu/edit?js,console)

The `a()` method will return a number if the `isSingle` parameter is set to `true`. If not, it will return the `this` object, allowing you to chain the `b()` method. This is might be a hack but I believe it solves your problem.

I write about Javascript and web development on my blog :) https://changani.me/blog

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.aValue = 0;
    this.bValue = 0;
  }

  /**
  * @param {Number} value
  * @param {Boolean} isSingle
  * @returns {Object/Number}
  */
  a(value = 0, isSingle = false) {
    this.aValue = value;
    return isSingle ? this.aValue : this;
  }

  /**
  * @param {Number} value
  * @returns {Number}
  */
  b(value = 0) {
    this.bValue = this.aValue + value;
    return this.bValue;
  }
}

const x = new Foo();

console.log("Should return 3: ", x.a(2).b(1));
console.log("Should return an 2: ", x.a(2, true));
console.log("Should return an instance of the object: ", x.a(2));
console.log("Should return 1: ", x.b(1));
console.log("Should return 0: ", x.a().b());
```

(https://jsbin.com/wozuyefebu/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to invoke methods on return value of methods, then, you should return `this` from those methods.  However, you will need an additional method, say `value()` to actuall get the result of sum.

A possible way is show below.

```js
class Foo {
  _a = 0;
  _b = 0;
  
  a(number) {
    this._a = number;
    return this;
  }
  
  b(number) {
    this._b = number;
    return this;
  }
  
  value() {
    return this._a + this._b;
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.a(1).b(2).value());
console.log(foo.b(5).value());
```